# Xorg eating up too much RAM on Ubuntu 9.10 box

Tags: ubuntu, memory, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

Xorg is eating up 444MB of 2GB total RAM on my Ubuntu 9.10 x86_64 machine with nvidia drivers installed for the nvidia G86 (GeForce 8300 GS). `top` shows:

```
top - 18:21:41 up 6 days,  2:40,  9 users,  load average: 0.46, 1.12, 1.22
Tasks: 266 total,   3 running, 262 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  8.4%us,  2.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.1%id,  0.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2055736k total,  1965136k used,    90600k free,     3952k buffers
Swap:   979924k total,   979908k used,       16k free,   102636k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                        
 1432 root      20   0 1154m 442m 7492 S    8 22.0  32:56.97 Xorg                                                                                                                                                                            
18462 yang      20   0 1001m 219m 8356 S    0 10.9   5:13.25 chrome                                                                                                                                                                          
24099 yang      20   0  865m  83m  13m S    0  4.2   0:06.91 chrome
```

`xrestop` shows:

```
xrestop - Display: :0.0
          Monitoring 47 clients. XErrors: 0
          Pixmaps:   40430K total, Other:     142K total, All:   40573K total

res-base Wins  GCs Fnts Pxms Misc   Pxm mem  Other   Total   PID Identifier    
1c00000    21   46    1   19  697     9128K     18K   9146K  3169 x-nautilus-desktop
1000000     4    3    0   17  194     9000K      4K   9004K  3134 gnome-settings-daemon
1600000    51    2    1   25 1100     7648K     28K   7676K   ?   compiz
```

For comparison, here's my other Ubuntu box, which also has compiz etc. enabled but with ATI RV370 (Radeon X300SE):

```
top - 18:18:18 up 58 days,  4:27,  9 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 224 total,   1 running, 223 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.8%id,  0.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1024964k total,   987124k used,    37840k free,   247012k buffers
Swap:  2048276k total,    94296k used,  1953980k free,   264744k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                        
24324 yang      20   0 61936  35m 6364 S    0  3.5   4:35.84 nxagent                                                                                                                                                                         
 1768 ntop      20   0  190m  32m 5388 S    1  3.2 283:36.15 ntop                                                                                                                                                                            
 1178 root      20   0 60588  29m 1788 S    0  3.0   5:48.89 console-kit-dae                                                                                                                                                                 
...
 1315 root      20   0  343m 4956 4020 S    0  0.5   3:43.87 Xorg
```

Any ideas on how to get to the bottom of this? (i.e. not "Log out"/"Reboot") Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make sure that you have the correct driver enabled in xorg.conf? You may want to put it on pastebin or something because its huge if you want us to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Not to put too fine a point on it, but you *are* using the nvidia drivers. There's no real way to troubleshoot them unless you work for nvidia.

It looks like there's some conflict or CPU-consuming issue in the driver somewhere--the CPU time on Xorg is *amazingly high*. Try another set of drivers, another distro, or use the ATi machine more.

(Me? I'm waiting for nouveau.)